# No puedo Interpretar el problema planteado

Tags: matrices

Solo necesito ayuda para entenderlo...Realizar un programa que pregunte con qué número desea llenar todas las posiciones de una matriz,  usted  elige  la  longitud  de  la  matriz,  luego  dicha  matriz  debe  aparecer  con  todos  los valores que el usuario eligió y la diagonal debe estar llena con el número 1.

Comment: Yo tampoco puedo. ¿Puedes poner algo de código? Se me da mejor el C++ que el Español.

Comment: ok.. pero cual es el problema.. agarras tu matriz, y la llenas con el numero que pediste.. y en la diagonal pones 1.. que es lo que no interpretas?

Comment: Estaba entre eso y que queria un dato para cada posicion de la matriz que no fuera la diagonal, y acudi a la comunidad para mayor seguridad

Comment: En base a tu comentario _Estaba entre eso y que queria un dato para cada posicion de la matriz que no fuera la diagonal_ me pregunto, en lugar de preguntarlo a la comunidad (que no conoce el contexto), ¿no sería mejor consultarlo con quien solicitó realizar dicho programa? De otra manera esto podría convertirse en un debate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basandome en la frase:

> con qué **número** desea **llenar todas las posiciones** de una matriz

Habla de solicitar UN sólo número con el que llenar TODAS las posiciones. Parece bastante claro, sino tendría que haber puesto:

... con qué número**S** desea llenar **cada una de** las posiciones ...

Comment: Gracias por tus correcciones y respuestas

Answer (score 0):

**Gracias por su ayuda, les dejo el código:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int numero, matriz[4][4];

    cout << "Ingrese un numero para rellenar la matriz ";
    cin >> numero;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Tu matriz resultado es:" << endl << endl;;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                matriz[i][j] = 1;
                cout << matriz[i][j]<<"     ";
            }
            else {
                matriz[i][j] = numero;
                cout << matriz[i][j]<<"     ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```